# How create an interactive menu with popup button (or pull down button)

Tags: swift, popup

I'm trying to create a context menu in my Swift app, but with the menu items interactive, i.e. from a database.

For example, I have an Array with countries. Sometimes this array can contain 5 items, other times 6 items and so on... and I try to create a menu with those items, but I can't. I think I'm too new for that.

My code is this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

setPopUpButton()

}


func setPopUpButton(){

        // Here are my Array with countries name. It's works fine.
        let statesOf = ArrayWithCountries()
        
        let optionClosure = {(action: UIAction) in
            print(action.title)
        }
       
        // In this part I want to fetch the countries array. Now it's a static menu!
        popUpButtonStates.menu = UIMenu(children: [
            UIAction(title: "Country 1", state: .off, handler: optionClosure),
            UIAction(title: "Country 2", state: .on, handler: optionClosure),
            UIAction(title: "Country 3", state: .off, handler: optionClosure),
            UIAction(title: "Country 4", state: .off , handler: optionClosure)
        ])
        
        popUpButtonStates.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        popUpButtonStates.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
    }
```

I have tried with a for loop. Something like this:

```
for country in countries{
UIAction(title: country, state: .off, handler: optionClosure)
}
```

But this solution it doesn't work.

Some help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how your "countries" array looks like but assuming it's just a list with countries:

```
// create the closure        
let optionClosure = {(action: UIAction) in
            print(action.title)
        }

// create an array to store the actions
var optionsArray = [UIAction]()

// loop and populate the actions array            
for country in countries{
    // create each action and insert the right country as a title
    let action = UIAction(title: country, state: .off, handler: optionClosure)
            
    // add newly created action to actions array        
    optionsArray.append(action)
}
        
        
// set the state of first country in the array as ON
optionsArray[0].state = .on

// create an options menu        
let optionsMenu = UIMenu(title: "", options: .displayInline, children: optionsArray)
        
// add everything to your button        
popUpButtonStates.menu = optionsMenu

// make sure the popup button shows the selected value
popUpButtonStates.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
popUpButtonStates.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
```

Comment: How to select one option with code? Suppose I want to update UI and select the second country?

Comment: @JackStark if you want to select a different country while populating the UI you can change the selected country's state to .on (instead of using country [0] like I did in this example). 
You need to make sure you don't exceed the array's boundaries as it will cause errors.  
For example, to select the second country:
**optionsArray[1].state = .on**

Comment: @AmirP thanks for that great comment. Do you know how the heck to set the selected item, once the menu is up and running ??  So something like `theButton.menu.children [12] .. state = .on` .. I can't figure it out for the life of me! Thanks for the awesome answer, bounty coming

Answer (score 2):

#### Even easier syntax for 2024 ...

```
yourButton.menu = UIMenu(children: strings.map({ s in
    return UIAction(title: s) { [weak self] _ in
        print("user selected \(s)")
    }
})
)
```